# Set specific years on JS datepicker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I was trying for a while but i didn't manage to find any solution...

So, this is a problem: I have one datepicker and some yearRange, for example '2010:2015'. This means that available years will be 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014 and 2015. But, what if i want to display only 2011 year and, for example, 2022?

Is there any option for that? Can i set some array of available years on datepicker? Something like:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  availableYears: ["2011", "2022"], //just a clarification of problem
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you want to show two distant years in a calendar (at first seems like a confusing UI)? What are you building?

Comment: Which datepicker are we talking about - jQueryUI? That doesn't have any such option. It would probably collide with the logic of the `<-` `->` arrows, that allow you to circle through the months and go into the next/previous year. When you are "in" December 2021, and click `->`, it goes to January 2022. I doubt that logic is equipped to deal with "holes" in the list of valid years at this point.

Comment: I have to build a form for some kind of personal card, where you have options for issue date and expiry date. So, expiry date only can contain two values (issue date + 5Y OR issue date + 10Y)

Comment: So the user can still select any arbitrary date for the expiry date? If the issue date was December 20th, then I could still select December 15th or even May 3rd, as long as it is in the year 5 or ten years from now ...? If that is _not_ the case, and issue date December 20th 2021 means, expiry date needs to be either Dec 20 2026 or Dec 20 2031 - then why even use a datepicker for _that_ part? Why not radio buttons to select either 5 or 10 years, and _automatic calculation_ of the expiry date?

Comment: @NenadJevtic in that case (since CBroe has pointed an emerging and serious problem!) you can always make only one input for the "From" date, and a select box  where the user selects "5 years" "10 years". And that's it.